# Cannot access ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

**Problem:**

Cannot access my ng-model.

*View (Jade):*

```
div(ng-repeat="(key, value) in questions track by $index")
    .question(ng-repeat="(keyTwo, valueTwo) in value")
        {{keyTwo}}
    .answer(ng-repeat="(keyThree, valueThree) in valueTwo")
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data" name="{{key}}" ng-value={{keyThree}}>{{valueThree}}
    <br>
    center
        input(type='submit' value='Submit' ng-click="check()" class='buttonLook')
```

*Controller:*

```
app.controller('individualClassCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $window) {
    $scope.check = function () {

            var foo = $scope.data; //undefined every time.
        };
...}
```

**What I have tried:**
I have read about the scope issue with the ng-repeat...so I explicitly set `ng-model="$parent.data"` and tried to access it that way... no success, I received $parent is undefined.

In addition I tried passing the model via `ng-click="check(data)"` with the necessary changes in my check function, still no luck. Any ideas?

I have tried digging around the various scopes in my terminal but I am not seeing anything.

Comment: `ng-value={{keyThree}}` You need quotes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of javascript inheritance. Because ng-repeat(similarly with ng-switch) creates it's own scope, you lose your original scope once you exist the repeat.

Initialize with

```
$scope.my = {data: null}
```

And now use $scope.my.data instead (adding the my should solve your issue).